# WinForms Usability and Best Practices

Tags: winforms, usability

What are some of the different Usability tips/tricks and best practices followed
with WinForms-based applications, or which are followed as a Standard?

These might be anything like font styles/sizes/color, number of controls on form, showing processing, error checking, themes, layout of controls, etc.

Any resources/links or checklists?

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic advice that I will give you is to look to other applications in your sector and do what they do. The users probably will be used to that style and would love to not have to learn new ways of working with the interface.

Also, chek this pdf, i've used it several times: [Usability guide](http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/WebForms_LukeW.pdf)

It canbe found here too: http://static.lukew.com/webforms_lukew.pdf

Comment: Access denied for the link. :(

Comment: @Ju-chan: Check the new link.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are lots of free/paid components to use. DevExpress components are my favorite (Grids, buttons, panels etc). Just google it o/